# Tolerance issue with MatrixExp

Tags: matrix, numerics

When I use `MatrixExp[m,v]` to compute, the error given by mathematica is

`` MatrixExp: Unable to satisfy Tolerance -> 1.4901161193847656`*^-8 for parameter value 0.6180060729365491`. ``

Here the matrix m is a large SparseArray with dimension 98*98, so I can not attach it.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you！

Comment: To be clear, you still get an output, correct? If this is correct, why not just raise the tolerance?

Comment: @ CA Trevillian Actually, there is no results outputted, and how to raise the tolerance? I have tried this  ```MatrixExp[m,v, ,Tolerance -> 10^(-12)]```, but it does not work.

Comment: A matrix of size $98 \times 98$ is not large. You can try to convert the sparse matrix to a dense one with `Normal` and try again. If you have to compute many exponentials for the same matrix, you may also consider using an eigendecomposition or a Jordan decomposition.

Comment: But on the other hand, the numerical error of `1.4901161193847656`*^-8` (whatever that means) might be acceptable. So you may also consider to simply ignore the message with `Quiet`.

Comment: Are you using machine precision? Have you tried using arbitrary-precision, e.g., `SetPrecision[m, prec]`